# Можно ли в редакторе CKEditor для разных полей задавать разный функционал редактора?

Tags: wysiwyg, ckeditor

Можно ли для разных `<textarea>` полей, которые находятся на одной странице,
подцепить CKEditor с разным функционалом?

Например, для одного поля функционал B, I, U. 
А для другого выравнивание текста и размер шрифтов?

**ВОПРОС СНОВА АКТУАЛЕН, так как решение из документации не помогает!**

> Defining Configuration In-Page
>
> The best way to set the CKEditor
> configuration is in-page, when
> creating editor instances. This method
> lets you avoid modifying the original
> distribution files in the CKEditor
> installation folder, making the
> upgrade task easier.
>
> In-page settings can be passed to any
> of the editor instance creation
> functions, namely CKEDITOR.replace and
> CKEDITOR.appendTo. For example:
>
> ```
> CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
>     toolbar: 'Basic',
>     uiColor: '#9AB8F3'
> });
> ```
>
> Note that the configuration options
> are passed through a literal object
> definition (starting with a "{" symbol
> and ending with a "}" symbol). Because
> of this the proper syntax for each
> option is (''configuration name'') :
> (''configuration value''). Be sure to
> not use the "equal" character (=) in
> place of the colon character (:).

Comment: так решена или актуальна ?

Comment: Более не актуальна. Просто ответ перенёс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ПРОБЛЕМА РЕШЕНА**

Для каждого поля можно писать свой конфигурационный файл:

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    customConfig: '/custom/ckeditor_config.js'
});
</script>
```